# Rewrite the power sum in terms of convolution

Tags: polynomials, combinatorics, number-theory, convolution

Let be an identity
$$n^{2m+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{m}A_{m,r}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^r(n-k)^r,$$ where $A_{m,r}$ are real coefficients, see [A302971](https://oeis.org/A302971) for numerators and formula of $A_{m,r}$. Here we can notice that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^r(n-k)^r$ is discrete convolution of power function it itself, defined on finite interval $[0,n-1]$. Let's define the power function $f_{r,n-1}(s)$, such that $f_{r,n-1}(s)*f_{r,n-1}(s)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^r(n-k)^r$
$$f_{r,n}(s)=\begin{cases}
s^r, \quad s\in[0,n],\\
0, \quad otherwise.
\end{cases}$$
So, now it would be smoothly seen that convolution of $f_{r,n-1}(n-1)$ to itself should be equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^r(n-k)^r$. The following code should have verify it, but it seems to me that it contains some mistakes,

```
f[m_, s_, n_] := Piecewise[{{s^m, 0 < s < n}, {0, True}}];
DiscreteConvolution[m_, n_] := 
  Sum[f[m, n - k, n]*f[m, k, n], {k, -Infinity, +Infinity}];
F[m_, t_] := DiscreteConvolution[t, m];
T[n_, k_] := F[n - k + 1, k];
Column[Table[T[n, k], {n, 0, 10}, {k, 0, n}], Left]
```

By this state, it gives correct convolution values of power function over $n$ as columns of the following table

```
 {{0}},
 {{1, 0}},
 {{2, 1, 0}},
 {{3, 4, 1, 0}},
 {{4, 10, 8, 1, 0}},
 {{5, 20, 34, 16, 1, 0}},
 {{6, 35, 104, 118, 32, 1, 0}},
 {{7, 56, 259, 560, 418, 64, 1, 0}},
 {{8, 84, 560, 2003, 3104, 1510, 128, 1, 0}},
 {{9, 120, 1092, 5888, 16003, 17600, 5554, 256, 1, 0}},
 {{10, 165, 1968, 14988, 64064, 130835, 101504, 20758, 512, 1, 0}}
```

But if I change the definition of function `f[m_, s_, n_]` from  `n->n-1` it produces the wrong values of convolutions. For instance, the discrete analog of above code

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0 | 0., 0 | 0.] = 1;
Protect[Power];
F[m_, t_] := Sum[k^t (m - k)^t, {k, 0, m - 1}];
T[n_, k_] := F[n - k, k];
Column[Table[T[n, k], {n, 0, 10}, {k, 0, n}], Left]
```

gives the correct result

```
 {{0}},
 {{1, 0}},
 {{2, 0, 0}},
 {{3, 1, 0, 0}},
 {{4, 4, 1, 0, 0}},
 {{5, 10, 8, 1, 0, 0}},
 {{6, 20, 34, 16, 1, 0, 0}},
 {{7, 35, 104, 118, 32, 1, 0, 0}},
 {{8, 56, 259, 560, 418, 64, 1, 0, 0}},
 {{9, 84, 560, 2003, 3104, 1510, 128, 1, 0, 0}},
 {{10, 120, 1092, 5888, 16003, 17600, 5554, 256, 1, 0, 0}}
```

That proves an identity
$$n^{2m+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{m}A_{m,r}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^r(n-k)^r,$$
**The problem:** How to redefine function `f[m_, s_, n_]` in existing code, such that it will produce correct values of convolution over various intervals ? Or how to rewrite the last one code in terms of convolutions of power function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's focus on the part that is giving you trouble: the term
$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}k^t(m-k)^t$, which is written in code as:

```
Sum[k^t (m - k)^t, {k, 0, m - 1}]
```

For example, with m=30, you get:

[image]

Your stated goal is to express this in term of a discrete convolution. Here's one way to do that. Let

```
kt = Range[0, 30]^t;
```

be one of the signals. Then the sum is equal to

```
conv = ListConvolve[kt, kt]
```

which turns the sum into a convolution. I have chosen to use ListConvolve because your convolution is over a finite number of terms whereas DiscreteConvolve is taken over a (doubly infinite) series, that is, over all k from -Infinity to +Infinity. To see these are the same:

```
FullSimplify[Sum[k^t (m - k)^t, {k, 0, m - 1}], Assumptions -> t > 0] === 
First@FullSimplify[conv, Assumptions -> t > 0]
```

returns True. The t>0 assumption is needed because otherwise the term 0^t is undefined.

Comment: This also gives a correct results, but I need have time to study on it. By the way, can you review my own codes ? May be can you see some errors ?

Comment: I used your example as follows:
    f[n_, r_] := Range[0, n - 1]^r;
    conv[n_, r_] := ListConvolve[f[n, r], f[n, r]];
The verification gives False:
    FullSimplify[Sum[k^t (m - k)^t, {k, 0, m - 1}], 
      Assumptions -> t > 0] === 
     First@FullSimplify[conv[m, t], Assumptions -> t > 0]

Comment: It surely needs to have something to work with... like a number for n. Look at conv[30,t] and you'll see it's identical to the corresponding sum.

Comment: Here the main idea to connect identity in odd power with convolutions of power difined on finite interval, above method gives wrong table using `Column[Table[conv[n - k, k], {n, 0, 10}, {k, 0, n}], Left]` and really I dont understand why

Comment: direct substitution `m=30` to `FullSimplify[Sum[k^t (30 - k)^t, {k, 0, 30 - 1}], 
  Assumptions -> t > 0] === 
 First@FullSimplify[conv[30, t], Assumptions -> t > 0]` gives `False` in my mathematica